# 500 internal server error when using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am receiving a 500 internal server error when making an ajax call.

Here is the javascript/jquery that makes the call:

```
$.ajax({url: 'ServicesAjaxHandler.php',
        data: {action: 'add'},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
```

And here is the php file being called:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'add' : add($_POST);break;
    }
}

public function add($data) {
    return 'test';
}
?>
```

`xhr.responseText` returns nothing.

Is there an issue with my PHP code that is causing this error?

Comment: You've got `public function` on line 10. You don't need the `public` part.

Comment: @andrewsi Great, looks like that was the issue. Have been doing a lot of object oriented programming lately got confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your functions before using them, EG:

```
function add($data) {
    return 'test';
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'add' : add($_POST);break;
    }
}
```

Using the keyword `public` is for Object oriented applications, if you have a setup like this:

```
class Test_Class { 

    public function add($data) {
        return 'test';
    }

}
```

using the keyword public will be acceptable, but since you are not using objects for your function interaction, take away the keyword for a working set

Comment: `case 'add' : add($_POST);break;` will not work. You need to change this also class/object concept.

Comment: I was not clear in my last comment. function `add` will not work as it is inside class. Need to create object of that class and access the method or have to make that method static.

Comment: Of you would prefer me to update my answer to show how you would reach the function, then I can.. I merely posted the class example to show the use of the public keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `public function` to just `function`.

```
function add($data) {
    return 'test';
}
```